# Is this question really 'too broad'?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30991992/how-to-get-difference-of-time-in-human-readable-with-laravel-5) was closed as being too broad and I was going to vote to reopen it, but I wanted to see what the community consensus was before I pushed it into the queue and also, I want to see if my thinking is correct (self audit?).

I personally don't see it as being too broad mainly because of what the question is asking:

> How to get difference of time in human readable **with Laravel 5**?

(emphasis mine)

**Firstly**, the question is asking for the "Laravel way" of doing what they are asking, and therefore it automatically removes the "broadness" from what I can see. If the question was asking for the PHP way (more generic) then I'd be voting to close too.

**Secondly**, the question only had / has one answer, and therefore one can safely say that this question isn't too broad and that there *is* a "Laravel way" to achieve what the user is asking. Obviously it could just be that the question was closed, hence no other answers were posted, but significant time had passed before the asking and the closure, yet no other answers were posted, from what I can see.

**Thirdly**, another indicator for it not being too broad (and the OP wanting solutions through Laravel) is that when the OP was provided with external approaches they commented with:

> huh...not at all, I was asking about a specific and existing function to get diff. of time IN laravel5.

So, is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30991992/how-to-get-difference-of-time-in-human-readable-with-laravel-5) really too broad?

### Edit #1

To clarify for the people that are viewing this after the original question was posted, the question that I'm am discussing was originally closed as too broad then reopened and then re-closed as dupe. The comments should clarify further what has gone on.

Comment: It might not be Too Broad (I've learned a thing or two about closure in 3 years) but it's definitely a dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508963/calculate-difference-between-two-dates-using-carbon-and-blade). There's no "Laravel way", incidentally. Laravel likes to use Carbon, which merely an extension of the PHP native DateTime class

Comment: @Machavity I was actually wondering if I'd be able to get one of the original closers to chime in and the only name that stood out was yours but I wasn't sure how to find you hence I left a comment on the question in the rare instance that one of you came across it. As for the dupe question that's fine by me (not looked at it, yet), my contention is mainly with the current close reason.

Comment: @Machavity looking at your linked question, it seems the one I'm talking about is older (more popular in terms of views too), so surely the one you linked is the dupe and I'd actually argue that the answer in the one that I've linked is better as it explains that this can be done with any date as long as it is defined within the `$dates` variable of a `Model`.

Comment: The newer is a much better question than the older. The older question, as written, is a bit poor IMO. With dupe directionality we intend to get traffic to the better question and answers.

Comment: Also, feel free to pop into SOCVR if you have questions about stuff we've closed. Am frequently in there

Comment: @Machavity I think you erred with that hammer. Getting traffic to the newer question was preferrable, IMO. Both question and answers are more useful.

Comment: Three of the close voters know nothing about [php] or [laravel].  So they probably assumed it was a task description and not a basic laravel question.  Typical chat room problem btw.

Comment: @yivi Yeah, in rereading it the Q here is too specific. The other is more generic. Duplicate VTC in progress

Comment: @yivi I have no qualms with editing the question to fix it up (as I have done now). Do say if it needs clarifying further.

Comment: @Machavity isn't generic good (obviously not too generic) but in this instance it seems fine. If I didn't know what Carbon was, I'd struggle finding your dupe. The only reason I found the one I linked was because I typed: '*laravel time since human readable*' and it popped up.

Comment: Great. That's what signposts are for. Now the question you linked will take you to the more informative answers.

Comment: @Script47 Isn't pointing people to the Carbon class (the Q is even tagged Laravel) a good way to help people find the answers they need? Duplicate closure isn't a penalty. The Q will remain for people to find

Comment: @HansPassant I can only find a recent request  (just posted minutes ago) in SOCVR. Which  chatroom do you mean in your comment?

Comment: @Machavity (and others) just to make it clear, I'm not rooting for either question, I'm just asking the questions that crop up for me to try and get the correct protocol in these instances for future references.

Comment: For those that are viewing either questions (the one I've linked or the one @Machavity linked), please vote responsibly. Don't just down-vote (or up-vote for that matter) for the sake of the "meta effect".

Comment: It's now accumulating re-open votes, for some reason? Meta is seriously weird.

Comment: @yivi I didn't reopen vote this time around, but it doesn't really scream duplicate to me. They both seem to be about relative times, but on two completely different problems and solutions.

Comment: @Tiny I guess I may be wrong, and not that I care that much. But I think that all the answers in the dupe say exactly how to accomplish what the asker wanted, using Carbon in Laravel. Exactly in the same way as the answer in the now closed question. But again, maybe I'm misreading things.

Comment: @yivi as far as I can tell, the newer one basically asks how to use Carbon, whereas the older one asks how to use dates, to which the answer is Carbon. Similar, definitely related, but not duplicate IMO.

Comment: Think if you weren't logged in and you typed _"Laravel human readable time difference"_, the first result is the question we're talking about. You would be redirected to the duplicate target, and I imagine you might be confused by what you see.

Comment: @yivi I voted reopen the first time however after it was closed as a dupe, I've not voted - though I don't agree with it being a dupe - otherwise we'd get stuck in a loop.

Comment: It is too broad as in "what is the specific problem you have" - it is merely a statement of intent thats not being followed by action - so essentially its a "Code this for me" and hence - too broad.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be all that broad to me.  The scope is well defined and clear and it's apparent that the question and answer have had a positive effect on the community.

I've cast a reopen vote on it.

Comment: I was going to include its popularity as one of the points but I thought against it as many questions that have been very popular have been previously closed - and rightly so - therefore its popularity is irrelevant. Good to know though.

Comment: Question is now closed as duplicate.

Comment: @Cœur:  It's not too broad though, is it? :P

Comment: @Makoto I prefer to pretend to know nothing about PHP... but OK, question didn't seem too broad: `now-date` gives you the elapsed seconds, `/60` gives you elapsed minutes, `/60` gives you elapsed hours, `/24` gives you elapsed days... whoah, I can even fit a full answer in two lines of comment.

Comment: @Cœur And your answer would be wrong: Carbon already has a function to format for humans, which should be used, and the original input is a string. Don't mislead future readers

Comment: @Bhyd:  This is Meta; I'm never planning on touching PHP so I don't particularly care about the purported accuracy of their answer.  I was just too confused by it since there was no context mandating that it was necessary, so I didn't really know how to respond.

Comment: I'd guess it was closed because it is essentially a "do my work for me" question without any demonstrated effort, which is considered a reason to vote 'too broad'.

Answer (score 3):

Although I agree that the question probably isn't too broad, it has characteristics that could nevertheless tend to attract too-broad close votes.  In particular, you are always better off, IMO, stating the appropriate scope and context for a question in the question text.  The title and tags can convey that information (and *should* convey at least some of it), but if the main text of the question covers all that explicitly then its chances of attracting close votes are reduced.  In this case, that would also reduce the chances of attracting close votes from people interpreting "Is there any function out there" as a request for a third-party library recommendation.

In response to your specific points:

> **Firstly**, the question is asking for the "Laravel way" of doing what they are asking, and therefore it automatically removes the
>   "broadness" from what I can see. If the question was asking for the
>   PHP way (more generic) then I'd be voting to close too.

That's not entirely clear to me even when I take the title and tags into account.  Yes, you can read the question that way, but the mention of Laravel 5 in title and tags does not automatically convey to me that the author is looking for a Laravel idiom specifically.  Would he have rejected a solution from a different direction?  Probably not.

> **Secondly**, the question only had / has one answer, and therefore one can safely say that this question isn't too broad and that there
>   is a "Laravel way" to achieve what the user is asking. Obviously it
>   could just be that the question was closed, hence no other answers
>   were posted, but significant time had passed before the asking and the
>   closure, yet no other answers were posted, from what I can see.

I'm sorry, but the evidence presented simply does not support the conclusion drawn.  That only one answer was posted just isn't well correlated with the specificity of the question.

> **Thirdly**, another indicator for it not being too broad (and the OP wanting solutions through Laravel) is that when the OP was provided
>   with external approaches they commented with:
>
> > huh...not at all, I was asking about a specific and existing function to get diff. of time IN laravel5.

That speaks to the author's *intent*, but it has little to do with whether the question, as posted, is too broad.  Its presence as a comment on the question does help, but this, too, would be better if integrated directly into the question.

---

So I guess I don't really buy any of your points, though I'm kinda on the fence about the first one, and I'm a little soft on the third.  This all supports my thesis: there's enough in the overall question to afford a reading as sufficiently specific, and if I'm charitable then I'll read it that way, but I can well understand others *not* reading it that way.  Such ambiguity could have been avoided by stronger and more complete question text.

Comment: '*Would he have rejected a solution from a different direction? Probably not.*' - He did. I addressed that in my post. But fair enough, I see where you're are coming from.

Answer (score -3):

I personally think it's clear that this question isn't too broad.

- The question asks 'Is there any function out there that I could use to make it easier?' (to achieve a specified result using a specific framework).
- There is one answer, that answers this specific question and provides that specific functionality.
- There are 10 upvotes for the question and 47 for the answer. If a question is well received, with an even better received answer, then I'd argue that the community recognition is a good guage of how well framed (and by extension specific) the question really is.

Comment: +25/-6 for Makoto's accepted answer, but +2/-6 for this answer that seems to have broadly the same thesis. I wonder what it is that people object to here. Perhaps the downvotes arrived before the edit?

Answer (score -4):

If you have a look at the **original state** of the question before it was closed as too broad:

> How to get difference of time in human readable with Laravel 5
>
> I want to put the difference of time between my updated_at column (in database using timestamp) and now. I want it to be human-friendly like so : 53 mins ago, 2 hours ago, 3 days ago, etc.
>
> Is there any function out there that I could use to make it easier?
>
> To be sure that you guys understand me, let's say I have in my database a column updated_at which is equal to 2015-06-22 20:00:03. It is now 20:00:28 so in my webpage I'd like to see : 25 mins ago. When it's higher than 59 minutes, I want to show only hours and when it's higher than 24 hours I'd like to see how many days ago.

Then I think there is adequate argument that this can be flagged as too broad as there is:

1. Nothing pertaining to current attempts
2. No "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"
3. No explicit issue / error, just - "can someone do this work
   for me."

Comment: You're clutching at straws there. All of those things are "nice to have" but this question doesn't come across as a "do this for me" question.  This is more of a "is there a better way to accomplish this" sort of thing.  I could at least see why it's easy to mistake at a glance, but I'd recommend not glancing so quickly at this question.